# Favorites model for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user and guideline model.

I would like a user to be able to mark a guideline as their favourite and then view a list of all their favourite guidelines.

It's not quite right.  I'm not sure if the 'favourite' action is adding a favourite correctly; or if it is adding correctly it's not displaying correctly in the favourites view (so 'show' action may not be right)...

**CONTROLLER**guidelines_controller.rb

```
def favourite
   type = params[:type]
   if type == "favourite"
    @guideline= Guideline.find_all_by_id(params[:guideline_id])
    current_user.favourite_guidelines << @guideline
     redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favourited #{@guideline.name}'
    elsif type == "unfavourite"
     current_user.favourite_guidelines.delete(@guideline)
     redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavourited #{@guideline.name}'

    else
    # Type missing, nothing happens
   redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end
```

**CONTROLLER**favourites_controller.rb

```
 def show

    @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
    if @user 
        @guidelines = @user.favourite_guidelines.all
        render action: :show
    else
        render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end
end
```

**ROUTES**routes.rb

```
get "guidelines/favourite"
  get "favourites/show"
```

**MODEL**user.rb

```
has_many :guidelines
 has_many :favourite_guidelines
```

**MODEL**favourite_guidelines.rb

```
  attr_accessible :guideline_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
```

**VIEWS**guidelines/index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
    <%= link_to "favourite",   guidelines_favourite_path(guideline, type: "favourite"), method: "get" %>
    <%= link_to "unfavourite", guidelines_favourite_path(guideline, type: "unfavourite"), method: "get" %>
```

**VIEWS**favourites/show.html.erb

```
<% if @guidelines %>
    <% @guidelines.each do |guideline| %>

        <div class="well">
            <%= link_to guideline.title, guideline %>
            <br />
            <%= guideline.content %>
            <br />
            Added <%=  time_ago_in_words(guideline.created_at) %> ago
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post the `params` from log??? `@guideline= Guideline.find_all_by_id(params[:guideline_id]); current_user.favourite_guidelines << @guideline` this has the problem. Why are you using `find_all`. `find_all` returns `array` and adding array into `array` which is giving wrong results I guess. So use `find`

Comment: First open your show page on browser. Then clear your log using command `$ > development.log`. Next click ur link to add fav. Then open file `$vim development.log`. You see parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment following returns `nil`:

```
@guideline= Guideline.find_by_id(params[:guideline_id])  #=> nil
current_user.favourite_guidelines << nil #Gives association mismatch error
```

I think `params[:guideline_id]` is `nil`. Post your params from log file.

Or try this:

Change your link to like this:

```
<%= link_to "favourite",   guidelines_favourite_path(guideline_id: guideline.id, type: "favourite"), method: "get" %>
<%= link_to "unfavourite", guidelines_favourite_path(guideline_id: guideline.id, type: "unfavourite"), method: "get" %>
```

In your earlier case:

```
 @guideline= Guideline.find_all_by_id(params[:guideline_id]) #=> []
 current_user.favourite_guidelines << [] #=> Valid and inserting nothing
```

Comment: thanks - changing this  to 'find_by_id' gives me an 'ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in GuidelinesController#favourite' - something to do with the relationships?

Comment: It shouldn't give error for changing it to `find_by`. Error is for something else. Can you paste exact error with full trace.

Comment: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in GuidelinesController#favourite

FavouriteGuideline(#70238325055960) expected, got NilClass(#70238318357120)
Rails.root: /Users/x/Projects/guidelines

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb:25:in `favourite'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"get",
 "authenticity_token"=>"a1Z9QAjGsOweKbLqbIaqe0fCOILLWlo4U6mALW8y4Pk=",
 "type"=>"favourite",
 "format"=>"23"}

Comment: I got your error. Its because `Guideline.find_by_id(params[:guidline_id])` is returning `nil`. `current_user.favourite_guidelines << nil` returns that error. In earlier case it was empty array so there was no error bcz `current_user.favourite_guidelines << []` valid one. So post your `params` from log.

Comment: Thanks for your persistence, now I'm getting: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in GuidelinesController#favourite

FavouriteGuideline(#70238325055960) expected, got Guideline(#70238324733360)
Rails.root: /Users/x/Projects/guidelines

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/guidelines_controller.rb:25:in `favourite'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"get",
 "authenticity_token"=>"a1Z9QAjGsOweKbLqbIaqe0fCOILLWlo4U6mALW8y4Pk=",
 "guideline_id"=>"24",
 "type"=>"favourite"}

Comment: I can't get the development log to work vim development.log is blank.  I realise this is me being dumb but I haven't used the development log before

Comment: Ya I got your params `Parameters: {"_method"=>"get", "authenticity_token"=>"a1Z9QAjGsOweKbLqbIaqe0fCOILLWlo4U6mALW8y4Pk=", "guideline_id"=>"24", "type"=>"favourite"}`.Now `guidline_id` is 24. Earlier there was no `guideline_id` in params.  And what you change in controller???

Comment: nothing in controller, just the find_by that you mentioned.  hasn't the guideline_id just been added because you asked me to change guidelines_favourite_path(guideline_id: guideline.id, type: "favourite")?